# return an observable correct

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, interceptor

I followed the last hours a tutorial about jwt refresh tokens but it seems that the code is a bit older and there were some changes. So I build an interceptor which got a problem with the Observable and I don't know how to fix it.

The Error is:

> "Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not
> include 'undefined'"

and I know it shows up because my Observable has no specific return.

My Code:

```html
intercept(request : HttpRequest<any>, next : HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> 
    {
        // Check if the user is logging in for the first time

        return next.handle(this.attachTokenToRequest(request)).pipe(
            tap((event : HttpEvent<any>) => {
                if(event instanceof HttpResponse) 
                {
                    console.log("Success");
                }
            }),
            catchError((err) : Observable<any> => { //Here comes the error message
                if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    switch((<HttpErrorResponse>err).status) 
                {
                        case 401:
                            console.log("Token expired. Attempting refresh ...");
                            return this.handleHttpResponseError(request, next);
                        case 400:
                            return <any>this.acct.logout();
                    }
                } else 
                {
                    return throwError(this.handleError);
                }
                //I think here should be a return but I don't know which kind, tried already a few ones
            })
            
           );

    }
```

I also can show you the original Code of the tutorial, that's the link:

https://dev.azure.com/Techhowdy/_git/NG_Core_AuthRTDB?path=/ClientApp/src/app/_helpers/jwt.Interceptor.ts

Comment: You need to return an observable. `throwError` will create an observable that emits an error with the value you give, so `throwError(err)` would be a good candidate.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense at least, ty!

Comment: No problem! What is `this.handleError` btw? Is it a function? It's a bit weird throwing a function.

Comment: Yes you can see it in my link above, just got it from a tutorial, still fighting with it because it dont works well :D Never did something with jwt refresh tokens

Comment: It's all a bit confusing. You have `handleHttpResponseError`, but it handles any http request, and not `HttpErrorResponse` as I would expect. At the same time, you have `handleError` that does handles `HttpErrorResponse`s. However, since you are in the else statement when you call it, you know that `err` is **not** an `ErrorHttpResponse`.

Comment: Mhmm i should better switch the whole thing to a better tutorial i think.

Comment: Maybe. What tutorial did you follow?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayTm_gxUJ1Y&list=PLHy1vgmVoz-KN3R5Grr30oW1dOW0VmWVT&index=1 the whole series.. But at least the token does not refresh. Much wasted time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catches errors on the observable to be handled by returning a new observable or throwing an error. [catchError](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError)

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Check if the user is logging in for the first time

    return next.handle(this.attachTokenToRequest(request)).pipe(
      tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          console.log('Success');
        }
      }),
      catchError((err): Observable<any> => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 401) return this.handleHttpResponseError(request, next);

        /**
         * I think the problem is here, the logout function does not return an observable and you can do like this
         */
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status === 400) this.acct.logout();

        return throwError(this.handleError);
      }),
    );
  }
```